# Prevent unmatched quote parse error in h2o importFile

Tags: r, word2vec, h2o

This is the popular pre-trained word vector file as supplied by the Stanford GLOVE project. It is commonly used for natural language applications.

The parse errors might be the root cause of some unpredictable behavior I am trying to fix. The strange stuff (not shown) appears after performing as.data.frame on this hex frame. So I'd like to fix this earlier error some way.

```
# How to eliminate parse error?
g6B = h2o.importFile(path = "/mnt/fastssd/glove/glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt", header=FALSE, na.strings=NA, sep=" ")

WARNING: ParseError at file nfs://mnt/fastssd/glove/glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt  at byte offset 7674; error = 'Unmatched quote char "' 
  |======================================================================| 100%
Warning message in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler):
“ParseError at file /mnt/fastssd/glove/glove.6B/glove.6B.100d.txt  at byte offset 7674; error = 'Unmatched quote char "'”
```

Is there a way within H2O to fix this error?  If not then what is another way? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot (head) of what's in that file?  I need to see what the format of that file is: sparse or CSV or something else?

Comment: got a similar error while reading the test file from Kaggle's "Two Sigma Connect: Rental Listing Inquiries" competition : https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-connect-rental-listing-inquiries/data

Answer (score 0):

I download the glove.6B.100d.txt test and did a quick try with latest H2O 3.10.4.3 in R and did see the same warning however the data was ingested correctly.

I could still use the data frame which had 399,999 rows and 101 columns properly so I can confirm that the data ingest was correct and the warning did not cause any problem in data ingest.

I have opened the following JIRA to fix the warning issue:

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4284